# OAuth Twitter to get request_token {"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]}

Tags: android, twitter, oauth

```
static public final String CUSUMER_KEY = "mcIgMJKcyhqFlAHK9batPvRvC";
static public final String CUSUMER_SECRET = "5PRVECiRPoddsBd70qGBfZZdJVPwWcxiicFf7usfS5nyhg4GGp";
static public final String ACCESS_TOKEN = "2320954854-eZYObTlxJ3Pqqd0YuGNlWcRQJQ4rNAyvsfsssV7";
static public final String ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = "iOEYAG5yEgRuWRh8MY5AIfwK2f2oF6HF9gAkzArTLQUKS";
static public final String REQUEST_URL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token";
static public final String ACCESS_URL = "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token";
static public final String AUTHORIZE_URL = "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize";
static public final String AUTH_URL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=";
static public final String CALL_BACK = "%22http%3A%2F%2Fmyapp.com%3A3005%2Ftwitter%2Fprocess_callback%22";
public String get_access_token(){
    String ret="";
    try{
        String sg_base_str = "POST&"+ URLEncoder.encode("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token", "UTF-8")+"&";
        String[][] data =
                {
                        {"oauth_consumer_key"    , CUSUMER_KEY  },
                        {"oauth_nonce"           , oauth_nounce()          },
                        {"oauth_signature"       , ""                       },
                        {"oauth_signature_method", "HMAC-SHA1"        },
                        {"oauth_timestamp"       , oauth_timestamp()        },
                        {"oauth_token"           , ACCESS_TOKEN        },
                        {"oauth_version"         , "1.0"       }
                };
        for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
            String _26;

            if(i + 1 < data.length) {
                _26 = "%26";
            }
            else _26 = "";

            if(data[i][0] != "oauth_signature")
            {
                sg_base_str += URLEncoder.encode(data[i][0],"UTF-8") + "%3D"
                        +  URLEncoder.encode(data[i][1],"UTF-8") + _26 ;
            }
        }

        ret =  hmacDigest(sg_base_str,CUSUMER_SECRET+"&"+ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, "HmacSHA1")+"\n\n"+sg_base_str;

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ret=ret.replaceAll("/","%2F");
    ret=ret.replaceAll("=","%3D");
    ret=ret.replaceAll("\\+","%2B");
    return ret;
}

public String oauth_nounce() {
    String uuid_string = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    uuid_string = uuid_string.replaceAll("-", "");
    String oauth_nonce = uuid_string;
    return oauth_nonce;
}

public String oauth_timestamp() {
    long millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long secs   = millis / 1000;

    return String.valueOf(secs);
}`public static String hmacDigest(String msg, String keyString, String algo) {
    String digest = null;
    try {
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec((keyString).getBytes("UTF-8"), algo);
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(algo);
        mac.init(key);

        byte[] bytes = mac.doFinal(msg.getBytes("ASCII"));

        String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, 0);
        digest = encoded;
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    }
    return digest;
}`
```

1. When I run code to get this: `oauth_nonce=252e7f4eee134ac2bf8cc287620ec2d9 oauth_timestamp=1433957398 oauth_signature=vAcm%2FNyc7S1RISe6jk7y8N1knMo%3D`
2. Then I has `POST https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token?oauth_consumer_key=mcIgMJKcyhqFlAHK9batPvRvC&oauth_nonce=252e7f4eee134ac2bf8cc287620ec2d9&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1433957398&oauth_token=2320954854-eZYObTlxJ3Pqqd0YuGNlWcRQJQ4rNAyvsfsssV7&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=vAcm%2FNyc7S1RISe6jk7y8N1knMo%3D`

and my result `{"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]}`

Tell me why?

Comment: Is there a reason you are manually creating the signature instead of using an existing OAuth library? OAuth 1 encoding/signing is notoriously complex.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing all the "http" 's to "https".